# Why does C++ not have Extend feature to virtual functions?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

C++ allows defining default behavior of member functions using the `virtual` keyword, but what if I want to *extend* a member function to perform additional functionality? For example, I have the following code:

```
virtual void OnSize(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    cxClient = LOWORD(lParam);
    cyClient = HIWORD(lParam);

    rect = { 0, 0, cxClient, cyClient };
}
```

`cxClient`, `cyClient`, and `rect` are member variables that are updated on receiving a `WM_SIZE` message. If I want to to update the scrollbar in an inheriting class, I would have to override the function to add in this functionality but then I would need to repeat the code for updating the member variables:

```
void OnSize(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) override {
    cxClient = LOWORD(lParam);
    cyClient = HIWORD(lParam);

    rect = { 0, 0, cxClient, cyClient };

    vScrollBar->setInfo(cyClient); // new functionality
}
```

Why does C++ not provide `extend` keyword to allow extending on the default behavior of a virtual function, that is, retaining the default behavior and incorporating additional functionalities. e.g:

```
void OnSize(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) extend {
    vScrollBar->setInfo(cyClient); // new functionality
}
```

Is this considered in the upcoming revision of C++?

Comment: *but then I would need to repeat the code for updating the member variables:* -- Your code could simply had been: `{ Base::OnSize(hWnd, lParam); vScrollBar->setInfo(cyClient); }`, assuming `Base` is the base class.

Comment: *"Why does C++ not provide extend keyword..."* **Because this can easily be achevied with current c++ and secondly nobody proposed such feature.** I would also recommend using a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: There's no point polluting the language with additional keywords for things that can already simply be done.

Comment: *Why does C++ not provide extend keyword to allow extending on the default behavior* -- All other languages that I know does this similar to C++.  You need to *call* the base class version explicitly (Java, C#, etc.) -- there is no "extend" keyword in those other languages that calls base functions automatically.

Comment: *"that is, retaining the default behavior and incorporating additional functionalities"* -- should the additional functionalities occur before or after the default behavior? *Providing a way to invoke the base class version of a function is more flexible than your proposed `extend`.*

Comment: To @JaMiT's point, what if you want to perform the extra functionality *before* you call the base class version?  How will an "extend" keyword work in that case?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `extend` keyword would be specifically for extending beyond the default behavior

Comment: @machine_1 But again, what if you want the default behavior *after* the custom behavior?  There are many frameworks where the derived class has to invoke the custom behavior, and then call the base class to "finish up" whatever job the base class is supposed to do.  Do you now see how your version of `extend` will not work?  As a matter of fact, since you are using Windows, the MFC architecture works this way, where the derived GUI object does something custom, but then must call the base class function to "finish up".

Comment: @user12002570 I know enough of C++ to get me going, though I have some deficiencies (i.e I did not know about Base::OnSize()). Am not going to open a 700 page book that's gonna tell me how a `while` loop works in the early chapters.

Comment: @machine_1 That's what I thought. Any beginner c++ book explains these basic things like calling base method in the derived class to use the functionalities provided by the base class. There's nothing wrong with reading a book. The best advise anyone can give other is to use a book.

Comment: in c++ you can have interfaces you can extend virtual methods and so much more with just one keyword `virtual`. Then there came the newer languages and thought all this is easier by introducing more keywords. Oh, and that most of the much more needs to go.

Comment: @machine_1 Skipping over the basic parts of a language manual -- e.g. how a `for` works -- without missing the points where even those basic parts might be different from other languages, is an aquired skill. And it *needs* to be aquired, because one day you *will* be asked to work in an unfamilliar language, with very little time to prepare, and little leeway for trial & error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `DerivedClass::OnSize()`, you can call `BaseClass::OnSize()` to achieve just what you want. No special keyword needed.

```
struct BaseClass
{
    virtual void OnSize(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) {
        cxClient = LOWORD(lParam);
        cyClient = HIWORD(lParam);

        rect = { 0, 0, cxClient, cyClient };
    }

    // ...
};

struct DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    void OnSize(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) override {
        BaseClass::OnSize(hWnd, lParam);
        vScrollBar->setInfo(cyClient);
    }

    // ...
};
```

The C++ committee is hesistant to add additional keywords to the language, especially for things that have always been possible without them. There is the danger of rendering existing code, which might use macros, compiler extensions etc., invalid by such extensions of the language proper. Hence, I would be rather surprised to see `extends` being considered for upcoming revisions of C++. The existing construct allows derived classes to have code both before *and* after the call to the base class functionality, which is actually superior to `extends`.

Answer (score 6):

One way around this issue is to provide two functions.  One concrete function that is not virtual that has the common code to run and then another virtual function that you call at the end of the concrete function that has the class specific behavior you want to incorporate.  That would look like

```
struct Base
{
    void do_action() { common_action; do_action_impl(); }
private:
    virtual void do_action_impl() {} // empty for the base class, you could have code here as well for the base class
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    //do_action is inherited
private:
    virtual void do_action_impl() { derived_specific_code; }
};
```

and now if you have a `Derived` object `d` calling `do_action` will call the base class function which will run the common code and then virtual dispatch to `d`'s `do_action_impl`.

Comment: With the limit that it applies just to one level... if a class inherit from `Derived`, we have to add another extra method (using `final` might be appropriate in such case...).

Comment: @Jarod42 Does it only apply to one level?  Works just fine here doing a second level: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71c45c05778d4c01

Comment: `D2` doesn't print "D1"... Might depend of the definition of OP for `extend` in such cases though (Another reasons why "extend" seems bad ;-) )...

Comment: @Jarod42 Aha, that's what you mean.  Yeah, this is only ever intended to run the base and the final derived objects code.